# Android passing bluetooth connection to another activities

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on an apps which is used to control a robotic car and the program is based on BluetoothChat, BluetoothChatService and DeviceListActivity.

In my First Activity, it is used to connect the Bluetooth and then jump to the next activity if connect successfully. The code is shown below:

```
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket = null;
...

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ...

}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    if(mService == null)
        setupControl();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(mService != null){
        if(mService.getState() == Service.STATE_NONE){
            mService.start();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mService != null) mService.stop();
}

private void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (mService.getState() != Service.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "not connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();       
        mService.write(send);       
    }
}

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    ...

};

public void onClick(View v){
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.tgbn_bt:

        ...

        break;

    case R.id.bt_connect:
            if(mBluetoothDevice == null && tgbn_bt.isChecked()==true){
            bt_connect.setText("Connect");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);  
        }
            ...
        }
            break;
        }
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String address = data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
            mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
            try{
                mBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            } catch (IOException e1){
                //TODO Auto-genterated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }       
            mService.connect(mBluetoothDevice);

        }
        break;  

}        
}
}
```

And the Service program is based on BluetoothChatService and i had just make a little bit modify on it

```
public class Service extends Application{
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "Service";
private static final boolean D = true;

// Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
private static final String NAME = "ProjectActivity";

// Unique UUID for this application
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// Member fields
private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private final Handler mHandler;
private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

/**
 * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
 * @param context  The UI Activity Context
 * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
 */
public Service(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}

/**
 * Set the current state of the chat connection
 * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
 */
private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    mState = state;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(ProjectActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}

/**
 * Return the current connection state. */
public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

/**
 * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
 * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
public synchronized void start() {

    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
 * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
 */
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
 * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
 * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
 */
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(ProjectActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(ProjectActivity.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}




/**
 * Stop all threads
 */
public synchronized void stop() {
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 * @param out The bytes to write
 * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
 */
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionFailed() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(ProjectActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(ProjectActivity.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionLost() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(ProjectActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(ProjectActivity.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

/**
 * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
 * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
 * (or until cancelled).
 */
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (Service.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
 * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
 * succeeds or fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            Service.this.start();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (Service.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }

}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(ProjectActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * @param buffer  The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(ProjectActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}}
```

Then, i want to pass the Bluetooth connection to the other activity, for example the control panel activity:

```
     public class ControlMethodActivity extends Activity {
static final String[] m=new String[] {"Arrow_Multi-Touch","Arrow_8 Buttons","Test2"};
//private TextView view;
private String holder;
private Spinner spinner;
private Button bt_Ok;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.control_method);

    bt_Ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_OK);
    bt_Ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(holder=="Arrow_Multi-Touch"){
                Intent i = new Intent(ControlMethodActivity.this,ArrowActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if(holder=="Arrow_8 Buttons"){
                Intent i = new Intent(ControlMethodActivity.this,Arrow8Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.method_spinner);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,m);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
            arg0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder = arg0.getSelectedItem().toString();         
        }


    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){

    }
});
    }}
```

What should I do?
Thank you for your nice advice and teaching....

Comment: You should be using a Service

Comment: I had based on the BluetoothChatService
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.html